# How to solve this Typeerror?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pyaudioanalysis

Using TensorFlow backend I am getting this Typeerror,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lwin/speech-emotion/Speech_emotion_recognition_BLSTM-master1/prediction.py", line 36, in <module>
    f = functions.feature_extract((y, sr), nb_samples=1, dataset='prediction')
  File "/home/lwin/speech-emotion/Speech_emotion_recognition_BLSTM-master1/utility/functions.py", line 17, in feature_extract
    f = audioFeatureExtraction.stFeatureExtraction(x, Fs, globalvars.frame_size * Fs, globalvars.step * Fs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyAudioAnalysis/audioFeatureExtraction.py", line 544, in stFeatureExtraction
    Win =Win.astype(int(Win))
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Comment: Show us the [mcve] that produces this.

Comment: The message you are getting is descriptive, to help you further, you need to include your code. And welcome to SO, please please take your time and read thru this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This is python code:  lowfreq = 133.33
    linsc = 200/3.
    logsc = 1.0711703
    nlinfil = 13
    nlogfil = 27
    Win =Win.astype(int(Win))
    Step = int(Step)

Comment: @thaingiW I dont really thing thats your whole code. Update your post with full indented code please

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you'll get error "only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars" when you are trying to pass an Array to function, which expects single value.

If you want to apply function which accepts single value on each item in Array, you can use [np.vectorize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html)

*Win* seems to be that Array, so *Win*.[astype](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html)(int) is correct casting.